# Download Zip file in php

Tags: php

I want to download my zip file by a variable ($direccion) that I want to assign to it and when I try to do it, it comes out that the file is corrupted.

```
$file_name = basename('C:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557.zip');
 
   header("Content-Type: application/Zip");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=26908557.zip");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize('C:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557.zip'));

  readfile('C:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557.zip');
   exit;
```

that's my code and it only works that way, but I want to put the $direccion path to it

```
$direccion='c:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/'.trim($cedula);
```

this is what my variable $cédula means    `$cedula=$_POST['cedula'];`

Comment: And what's the problem in doing exactly that? Anything not working with the user-specified file name?

Comment: Does `$cedula` include the ".zip" suffix as well? Or only the file number?

Answer (score 0):

There many ways of zip file creation which are;

```
$zip_file = '(path)/filename.zip';$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$zip_file = $dir . '/filename.zip';$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ( $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
exit("message");
} $zip->addFile('full_path_of_the_file', 'custom_file_name); $download_file = file_get_contents( $file_url );
$zip->addFromString(basename($file_url),$download_file); $zip->close();
```

Or simply do this:

```
$url = "http://anysite.com/file.zip";$zip_file = "folder/downloadfile.zip";$zip_resource = fopen($zipFile, "w");$ch_start = curl_init();curl_setopt($ch_start, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);curl_setopt($ch_start,CURLOPT_FILE,$zip_resource);$page =curl_exec($ch_start);if(!$page){echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch_start);}curl_close($ch_start);$zip = new ZipArchive;$extractPath = "Download File Path";if($zip->open($zipFile) != "true"){echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";}$zip->extractTo($extractPath);$zip->close();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What have you changed, and why?

Answer (score -2):

```
class FileNotFound extends RuntimeException {}

$downloadUploadedZip = function(string $filename): void {
    $directory = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload';

    if (dirname($filename) !== '.') {
        $directory = dirname($filename);
    }

    $filename = basename($filename);
    $filepath = sprintf('%s/%s', $directory, $filename);

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header(sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s", $filename));
        header(sprintf("Content-Length: %d", filesize($filepath)));

        readfile($filepath);

        exit;
    }

    throw new FileNotFound(sprintf('File %s not found.', $filepath));
};

$downloadUploadedZip('26908557.zip');
$downloadUploadedZip('C:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557.zip');
```

Comment: Interesting how the comments that drove the downvotes got deleted, leaving no context for why they occurred (a demand to add "some explanation", followed quickly by the downvotes). This even though there is still a completely incorrect answer above this one with the same request for "some explanation", no downvotes but the comment persists.